# Where did my followers go in Fable 3?

Tags: fable-3

After I beat the darkness, I noticed that the only people that are left are me and the citizens of Bowerstone. What happened to all of my followers like Paige and the others?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is, once the story is over, the game is pretty much over. All that's left is open world roaming. So basically; they're gone. Disappeared like they never were.

Comment: But the didn't just disappear because the were there during Walters funeral

Comment: that's technically still part of the story

Comment: Oh, well that stinks... Anyway thanks for the answer

Comment: Glad I could help, sorry it wasn't what you were looking for